# Image not posted on facebook by android app

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, photo

Hi I am using a tutorial to post image on facebook but its not posting. Please guide what i am doing wrong. I have facebook.apk installed on mobile. I have done extactly what is described on Facebook developer guiide.

Here is the error....
[image]

```
public class DummyActivity extends Activity {
Facebook facebook = new Facebook("xxxxxxxxxxxx");

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
             byte[] data = null;

             Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
             ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
             data = baos.toByteArray();

             Bundle params = new Bundle();
             params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
             params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
             params.putByteArray("picture", data);

             AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
             mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);
        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

        public void onError(DialogError e) {}

        public void onCancel() {}         
    });
}




@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Here is another class,

```
  public class SampleUploadListener implements RequestListener {

public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      try {
            // process the response here: (executed in background thread)
            Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Response: " + response.toString());
            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
            final String src = json.getString("src");

            // then post the processed result back to the UI thread
            // if we do not do this, an runtime exception will be generated
            // e.g. "CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original
            // thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.w("Facebook-Example", "JSON Error in response");
        } catch (FacebookError e) {
            Log.w("Facebook-Example", "Facebook Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

}

public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: what's the server's response?

Comment: You don't need to put `AccessToken` in the params.

Comment: Hello, you mean to say this line,              params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i managed to log in, and posted is it the right response...

```
02-13 14:48:55.949: D/Facebook-Example(2814): Response: {"pid":"100002384000781_493454","aid":"100002384000781_53368","owner":100002384000781,"src":"http:\/\/photos-h.ak.fbcdn.net\/hphotos-ak-ash4\/400189_233648050057993_100002384000781_493454_803419378_s.jpg","src_big":"http:\/\/a8.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net\/hphotos-ak-ash4\/400189_233648050057993_100002384000781_493454_803419378_n.jpg","src_small":"http:\/\/photos-h.ak.fbcdn.net\/hphotos-ak-ash4\/400189_233648050057993_100002384000781_493454_803419378_t.jpg","link":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/photo.php?fbid=233648050057993&set=a.233615786727886.53368.100002384000781&type=1","caption":"","created":1329124670,"object_id":233648050057993}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong parametes!

Check the [documentation of photos.upload](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/photos.upload/)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this,

```
    Bundle params = new Bundle();

                try {
                    Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(config.downloaded_image_path);
                    Log.i("Path",config.downloaded_image_path);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
                    bMap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
                    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray(); 
                    params.putByteArray("photo", b);
                } catch  (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                params.putString("caption", config.facebook_comment);
                Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", params, "POST", new PhotoUploadListener(), null);
```

Try changing the keyvalue for param as "photo" instead of "picture" and in the request method you are providing null for GRaphApi which is certainly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one [FB](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/hackbook/)

it may helps you.